# how change shipping methods radio into dropdown magento2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 I am trying to change shipping methods as the dropdown in the cart which I always brought shipping methods in the cart so I change the radio to dropdown so it showing error like:

> `Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return 
>      $parent.getRatesForGroup($data) }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return (available) }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "options: function (){return $parents[1].selectShippingMethod }"
>   Message: Cannot write a value to a     ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
>       at     dependentObservable (knockout.js:1785)
>       at    applyToObject (knockout.js:4089)
>       at    optionForArrayItem (knockout.js:4116)
>       at    ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:5222)
>       at    evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
>       at    Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
>       at mapNodeAndRefreshWhenChanged (knockout.js:5221)
>       at Object.ko.utils.setDomNodeChildrenFromArrayMapping (knockout.js:5334)
>       at update (knockout.js:4155)
>       at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)`

My code is: which input type radio I changed like below in `shipping_rates.html`.

```
<select data-bind="optionsText: $parents[1].selectShippingMethod, options: $parents[1].selectedShippingMethod, attr: {value: carrier_code + '_' + method_code, id: 's_method_' + method_code}"></select>
```

So please do the needful.